# Manual Math.pow using BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, exponent

I am trying to write a manual code for Math.pow and that too using the BigDecimal data type as i would be working with very small values later.

I got this code for math.pow which i then tried to convert to BigDecimal.

```
public static double power(double base, int exponent) {
double ans = 1;
if (exponent != 0) {
    int absExponent = exponent > 0 ? exponent : (-1) * exponent;
    for (int i = 1; i <= absExponent; i++) {
        ans *= base;
    }

    if (exponent < 0) {
        // For negative exponent, must invert
        ans = 1.0 / ans;
    }
} else {
    // exponent is 0
    ans = 1;
}

return ans;
}
}
```

I converted the double and int data type to BigDecimal and tried to change the code accordingly too but somehow I do not get the correct results.

```
 public static BigDecimal powerBig(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal exponent) {

    BigDecimal ans=  new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal k=  new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal t=  new BigDecimal(-1.0);
    BigDecimal no=  new BigDecimal(0.0);

    if (exponent != no) {
         BigDecimal absExponent =  exponent.signum() > 0 ? exponent : t.multiply(exponent);
        for (int i =  1 ; i <= absExponent.signum(); i++) {
            ans =ans.multiply(base);
        }

        if (exponent.signum() < 0) {
            // For negative exponent, must invert
            ans = k.divide(ans);
        }
    } else {
        // exponent is 0
        ans = k;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

I am trying to run it on

```
 BigDecimal check =  new BigDecimal (4.0);
 BigDecimal Euler = new BigDecimal (2.7182818);

  powerBig(Euler,check);
```

But all i get as an output is the teh Euler value. Can somebody help me with the error i have in my code ?

The code runs now after changing the exponent type to int

```
public static BigDecimal powerBig(BigDecimal base, int exponent) {

    BigDecimal ans=  new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal k=  new BigDecimal(1.0);
    //BigDecimal t=  new BigDecimal(-1.0);
    //BigDecimal no=  new BigDecimal(0.0);

    if (exponent != 0) {
         int absExponent =  exponent > 0 ? exponent :  (-1)*exponent;
        for (int i =  1 ; i <= absExponent; i++) {
            ans =ans.multiply(base);
        }

        if (exponent < 0) {
            // For negative exponent, must invert
            ans = k.divide(ans);
        }
    } else {
        // exponent is 0
        ans = k;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: `exponent != no` - what do you think this does? Not even `equals` works with `BigDecimal`, why would you think that `==` would?

Comment: I changed it to exponent.signum() > 0 but still it doesnt work

Comment: Given that [`BigDecimal.sigNum()` returns `{-1,0,1}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#signum()) what on earth does `for (int i =  1 ; i <= absExponent.signum(); i++)` do? In short, debug your code - the issues are all from a lack of attention...

Comment: I am trying to run the loop of multiplication of base (finding exponent) for as many times as the exponent is.

Comment: Further, this obviously doesn't work with factional values, so why not just use [`BigDecimal.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow(int))??

Comment: And could you tell me, in words, what that loop _actually_ does given what `sigNum` does?

Comment: Thank you Boris ...I changed a few things and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that BigDecimal.sigNum() returns 1, 0 or -1 if the number is positive, zero or negative so absExponent.sigNum() will allways return 1 an your loop will end at the first time it's executed

This version worked with the euler example

```
public static BigDecimal powerBig(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal exponent) {

    BigDecimal ans=  new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal k=  new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal t=  new BigDecimal(-1.0);
    BigDecimal no=  new BigDecimal(0.0);

    if (exponent != no) {
        BigDecimal absExponent =  exponent.signum() > 0 ? exponent : t.multiply(exponent);
        while (absExponent.signum() > 0){
            ans =ans.multiply(base);
            absExponent = absExponent.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
        }

        if (exponent.signum() < 0) {
            // For negative exponent, must invert
            ans = k.divide(ans);
        }
    } else {
        // exponent is 0
        ans = k;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

also BigDecimal class have a pow function so if you want to keep simple you can just put

```
 BigDecimal Euler = new BigDecimal (2.7182818);
 Euler.pow(4);
```

Comment: This is going to break horribly if exponent isn't an integer. So.. why not use BigDecimal.pow?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a chance that the `else-clause` will be executed? As long as `no` is created with a new object, `no != exponent` will always hold true.